# How should hierarchical permissions be implemented efficiently in microservices?

Tags: microservices

I have a scenario where user permissions are scoped to a particular position in a hierarchy, e.g. a user may have permissions at a building, whereas another user only for a room inside that building. Resources can also be scoped at a particular position in the hierarchy.

I would like to allow for different entity types to define their own rules for whether a user can see a particular resource or not. E.g. a particular resource may be visible by anybody with permissions at or above the scope of the resource, whereas another may have a strict requirement that the user has to have the permission at exactly the scope of that resource.

The approaches I have thought of so far are:

1. Each microservice has a sidecar service which caches the hierarchy required for working out whether a particular resource is visible, but this then essentially requires the hierarchy to be located with all deployed microservices.
2. A single authorization service which is called to determine whether permission should be granted to perform an action for a particular resource.
3. Each microservice queries the hierarchy from the service which owns the hierarchy when needed, in order to retrieve the required information to determine the permission check itself.

Information around this particular style of permission in a microservice environment seems to be limited. What would be the recommended approach for such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend **approach 2**, for the reason that your application will be unlikely to be the only *consumer* of the auth service as your architecture expands.

You would query the auth service whenever a user logs into any of your applications, and this would return a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) with the permissions allocated to the particular user baked into it. Then when the user attempts to access the restricted resource, the `Buildings` service (or similar) would query the JWT to see if they have the appropriate permissions, and return the content that they have access to.

Comment: My only concern with the JWT approach is that the JWT itself could become extremely large. Imagine a very large office building, which has many floors, within that, many rooms, and within them, many desks. Storing a GUID for each of these which a user may have access to within a JWT may exceed the HTTP header size limit.